# Force Log in to view a page

Tags: conditional-content

So I have a page (ex. site.com/start) where I want to show a login page (ex. site.com/start/login) if not logged in, in order to view the page.

Without using any plugin, what would be the condition logic which if user visits `/start` page, while they are not not logged in, then the user is redirected to `/start/login` page instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a template file, this should do it:

```
<php
If (!is_user_logged_in())
{
   wp_redirect( "start/login" );
   exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the login page you want to send visitors to is the regular WordPress login page, then you can use the built in `auth_redirect` function. Put this code at the top of your template file:

```
<?php auth_redirect(); ?>
```

This code will do the following:

**If user is logged out**

1. Redirect the user to the default login page of WordPress.
2. After login, redirects the user back to the current page.

**If user is logged in**

- Page renders as normal, no login redirect.

More documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect